# DJI SDK SWIFT - implement FollowMeMission sample code

Tags: ios, swift, dji-sdk

I'm trying to add follow me mission to my app (base on DJI SDK), I am not found any sample code or introduction how to use this class, can anyone can help ?

Thanks Yakir.

Comment: Have you tried converting the Objective C example on DJI's github to Swift? It should be fairly straightforward. There is also a Swift example for a Timeline mission in the same repo. Here is the link

Comment: https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-iOS/blob/master/Sample%20Code/ObjcSampleCode/DJISdkDemo/Demo/MissionManager/FollowMeMissionViewController.m